# Xamarin Forms application architecture

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am developing an app for iOS, Android and Windows using Xamarin forms. From their web site application architecture [image]

shared code such as DAL or BL goes in Shared code folder and UI layer in platform specific folders. 
Looking at the sample code from Xamarin, the UI code is also in the shared code folder and only platform specific features in platform folder.

Now, it is confusing as where to have the UI specific code. 
My UI include some list views and plain views. nothing much platform specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That [image](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_3_-_setting_up_a_xamarin_cross_platform_solution/) illustrates code sharing with Xamarin Platform projects (Xamarin Android and Xamarin iOS), not Xamarin Forms.  Platform projects do not have any shared UI.

For a Xamarin Forms project, you would place any shared UI code in your shared project.  Any custom renderers or other platform specific UI would go in the individual platform project.